# Jersey with JSPs, without tags

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, jersey

I am using Jersey to do the URL binding for my web application. Hence, I am using it as a very simple MVC. I can manage to have Jersey return my JSPs, however:

When I pass my model to the view, it is passed as "it" -- and I can access it on my JSP using tags, ala: ${it}, however, I want to use it as a JSP variable, via <%= it %>

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: because I am experimenting with a new framework -- i want to pass in many html blobs and i want to access them via it.get("main"), it.get("footer"), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally [fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to see why you would ever do that, but anyway, the *scriptlet* equivalent of the EL expression

```
${it}
```

would be

```
<%=pageContext.findAttribute("it")%>
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments:

> *because I am experimenting with a new framework -- i want to pass in many html blobs and i want to access them via it.get("main"), it.get("footer"), etc*

Just make it a `Map<String, Something>` or a Javabean class, then you'll be able to get them by

```
${it.main}, ${it.footer}, etc
```

where `main`, `footer`, etc are `Map` keys or Javabean properties. It'll return the value.

Comment: wow, youre absolutely right, thats for the great suggestion. I was unaware that EL allowed one to access maps like that. Does EL allow one to pass in arguments? like it.doSomeCalc(1)?

Comment: Only when you run on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc) with the webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml` declared conform Servlet 3.0. Invoking methods in EL was only possible since EL 2.2, you see. However, this is not necessarily the best practice, it depends on the functional requirement.

Comment: i see, thans a bunch, im using jetty 6.1, ill look into it

Comment: Jetty 6 is a Servlet 2.5 container, so forget it. Go ahead with prepopulated maps.